# Handlebars 4.0.5: "Unknown template object: object" when running from Browser Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I am trying to do some Handlebars templating.
To get started, I followed the first example on the Handlebars main page (http://handlebarsjs.com/):

Template:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="body">
      {{body}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Compiling:

```
var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

Executing:

```
var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"};
var html    = template(context);
```

I always get the following error:

> "Unknown template object: object"

I downloaded Handlebars 4.0.5 directly from the server (http://handlebarsjs.com/installation.html) and I tried with both jQuery 3.1.1 and 2.2.4 as well.

If I try to google that issue, I only get references to older Handlebars version.

Can someone please help me?

EDIT:
In fact the issue seems to occur only when running the template from the (chrome) browser console.
Is there any solution for this?

Since for productive use, I have a rather complex JSON-structure, I'd like to use the template with, using the template from browser console for debugging and testing purposes would be quite helpful...

Comment: There must be something else going on - works as it should https://jsfiddle.net/633gzf4x/ and using 4.0.5 https://jsfiddle.net/633gzf4x/1/

Comment: This issue seems to occur only when running the template from browser console, see my "EDIT" statement above...

Comment: Have you tried using debugger? making sure handlebars is loaded first

Comment: In fact, Handlebars is correclty loaded. Compiling the template works fine also. The error occurs when running the compiled template function and passing the runtime data. At least I've found someone on GitHub experiencing the same issue: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1281

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs in the console *and* Chrome is currently stopped at a breakpoint. Console commands can be executed even when the code is not stopped. Try running your code from the console when a breakpoint is not active.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your source `source` variable. Make the following change:

From: `var source = $("#entry-template").html();`

To: `var source = $("#entry-template").text();`

The Handlebars.compile() function expects a string.